# How to get original folder name and subfolder names while uploading whole folder. (using php)

Tags: php, html

I created php script which can upload whole folder even with it's sub folders in it. Problem is, that it's only uploading files in the folder and its subfolders and I need to get names of this folders and subfolders. I do not need tmp_dir I need names or paths of original folder and its subfolders.

Comment: Do you have any code to start with?

Comment: Did you try dumping the info from post $_FILES super global? <?php print_r($_FILES) ?> ? Maybe you can find the info there.

Comment: no there is no folder name in $_FILES (only tmp_dir)

Comment: Are you talking about the original file paths on the clients machine?

Comment: You can't. Uploaded files only store source file names, not client directories. One alternative is sending files within a zip file with the whole structure.

Comment: It's all right guys I already got the solution :D Using Javascript I'm able to get full paths of files from my computer, insert them into hidden input and send them with uploaded files.